# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\pyrll\index.php on line 58

Tags: php

am trying to fetch values from the database but i get an error message  "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\pyrll\index.php on line 58". Can someone help me?

here is the code:
   `

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project ORDER BY  projectid DESC ");

while($rowsres = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //line 58

echo "$rowsres[projectname]";

?>`
```

Comment: Add code please; we can't point you to your problems if you don't show us what you have.

Comment: Add your php code that you are using to fetch the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that:

1. You don't have an active database connection
2. The query result does not yield anything (ie the response is NULL) or
3. There is a syntax error in your query

I would use a program like Toad (Windows) or Sequel Pro (Mac OS) or good ol' terminal to check that your query yields a result.

If you are using something like a ***sprintf()*** to assemble your query from variable, ensure that you are getting the proper string output with an echo.

> mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
>
> ```
> die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
> ```
>
> mysql_select_db("mydb");
>
> **$result** = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

```
Check that the query string (SELECT id, name FROM mytable) works externally
```

> eg. echo $query = sprintf("SELECT id, name FROM mytable WHERE id = %d",$var);

if echo $query yields something like:

```
[GOOD]: SELECT id, name FROM mytable WHERE id = 5
```

else

```
[BAD]: SELECT id, name FROM mytable WHERE id =
```

If the outputs well, then the rest should work just fine. Unless of course you don't have access to a database.

> while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
>       printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);
>   }

Comment: thanks i checked the db connection and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Without the code you are using it's hard to say. But mostly this error occurs when the previous mysql_* function failed and it did not return a result. Instead try to use `mysql_*(<blabla>) or die(mysql_error())` for verifying the function worked.

As a side note, try to refrain from mysql_* functions; they are in the depreciation process. Use mysqli_* or PDO.